# PDF won't be displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to integrate a PDF in a browser window. I tried `embed` and `iframe`, as well as `pdfobject.js` . For some browsers, it works, for others not.

In Google Chrome, I get the error message `Error loading PDF document` (in German), but only when the PDF is hosted at my server. If the same PDF is hosted somewhere else, it works. I could not find significant differences in the HTTP response headers.

Here is my code, using `pdfobject.js`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pdfobject.com/scripts/pdfobject.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="ol()">

<div id="pdfRenderer" width="200" height="200"></div>

<script>
function ol() {
var pdf = new PDFObject({
  //url: "http://share.rinntech.com/offerrequest/productinfo/Arbotom.pdf",
  //url: "http://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf",
  url: "http://share.rinntech.com/sample.pdf",
  id: "pdfRendered",
  pdfOpenParams: {
    view: "FitH"
  }
}).embed("pdfRenderer");
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

For some reason, this code does not work in jsfiddle!

The PDF http://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf will be displayed, but http://share.rinntech.com/sample.pdf not. What can I do?

Note: Disabling `Content-Disposition: attachment` in Apache does not help to solve the problem.

Comment: Are the permissions on the pdf itself okay? What permissions are on the file?

Comment: You should give PDF.js a try: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: pdfobject uses adobe reader. which means you need to have that installed on your client and working with the browser. I would try http://viewerjs.org/

Comment: @Pogrindis I have Adobe Reader installed.

Comment: @Stormie What do you mean with permissions? This tab in Adobe Reader http://imgur.com/pDhvKRJ ? Seems ok to me.

Comment: The pdf you're trying to view is hosted online right? Are it's file permissions set correctly? Sorry if I've misunderstood the question!

Comment: @Stormie You can try it out yourself. The PDFs can be downloaded via Apache, so Apache has read permissions, if you mean that. It is a browser problem.

Comment: ViewerJS (which uses pdf.js) seems to be a very good tool. I am currently testing it. But is there a chance that hyperlinks can be clicked?

Comment: ViewerJS was the first tool I tested. Alas, there are some problems, e.g. the mouse wheel is not usable, and links cannot be clicked. That is weird, since it uses PDF.js . PDF.js solved my problem and it seems to be a very good solution. Please post it as answer, so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not find significant differences in the HTTP response headers.

The only difference with response headers is, significantly, the one that prevents you from viewing the PDF as you want:

On your site

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment
```

On site that works ... no `Content-Disposition` header

Comment: I wrote "Note: Disabling Content-Disposition: attachment in Apache does not help to solve the problem." at the end of my post. I already tried it without this header, and it didn't work.